# Get the list of users who are using database/schema/table

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, psql

There is one use case in my project where i want to show the user who has got the access to use that database/schema/table in postgresql. Suppose I have created a database employee. So I want list the users who are accessing this database. Same for schema and tables. I tried this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    information_schema.tables 
WHERE 
    table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND 
    table_schema not like 'pg_toast%'
```

But it gives information about current user has access to. I want the list of accessing users that are using that database/table/schema/column.

Comment: If you have UpdatedBy and UpdatedAt in your columns you can query each tables by 'UpdatedBy/UpdatedAt' so you can have the list of users that used those tables

Comment: means i will have to add extra column in my table which ever i have created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `has_table_privilege()` to achieve what you want.

`select has_table_privilege('user_name', 'schema.table', 'select');`

More info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE.html).

I suppose you need to be a superuser to get all results. Below shows all the users who ***have*** privileges, not necessarily whether they are accessing the tables.

Now you can tweak the query to join all users with list of tables -

```
SET search_path TO public,
      schema1;

SELECT *, 
       usename,
       has_table_privilege(usename, table_schema||'.'||table_name, 'select') as has_privilege
FROM SVV_TABLES
JOIN PG_USER
ON 1=1
WHERE table_schema = 'schema1';
```

Comment: It is working for redshift. Thank you. But, What if I am not using redshift, I am using simple postgresql. Then instead of SVV_TABLES which table will be used